# A problem with youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube

I am trying to use the youtube video downloader youtube-dl
but when trying to use for downloading videos I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 29, in <module>
 import gzip
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

Any help????

Comment: How you installed youtube-dl ? From repository or from source

Comment: I installed it using `sudo apt-get`

Comment: Python 2.5? You are doing something wrong, try removing the Python 2.5 installation in `/usr/local`. You are potentionally breaking your whole Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to update the software using the embedded update function :

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```

Maybe this could solve some bugs/problems.